# jQuery DatePicker Not Highlighting in Custom Style Sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I am using the jQuery DatePicker and i've got the following code which is supposed to change the default date to the one I have specified, in this example it is supposed to default and highlight 18th August 2017.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    jQuery("#date").datepicker('setDate', new Date('2017-08-18')); 
});
</script>
```

However, although it does actually default to date, if I use my default stylesheet provided in my theme template then it does't actually highlight the date and remove the old default highlighted day.

If I use the jQuery example stylesheet below, then it seems to work:

```
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
```

But if I use the stylesheet below provided in my theme, then it doesnt work:

```
http://themetrace.com/demo/shamcey/css/style.default.css
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that will work perfectly . I just tried that in shamcey demo page in the console . It worked perfectly[image]

this is after i executed the code

[image]

Add this style in your style sheet

```
<style>
    .ui-state-active{
     background:#a5d2ff
    }
</style>
```

"#a5d2ff" is the color . You can replace with what ever color you want. This is the screen shot after i added that style 
[image]

Comment: That's what I was saying, it does select the date correctly, but if you click on it to see the graphical elements, the date is not highlighted as a dark blue.

Comment: I have added the css code above .. add that code in your style sheet or in your html code using that style tags .. I have added the screenshot of the working code which is highlighting the date

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain, but I believe that there may be an issue with the jQuery ui version 1.9.2 stylesheet you are using. I was getting the same results you described while testing the snippet below with your provide style link. I changed the included jQuery UI library to use the later 1.12.1 version and was able to see things highlighted as expected. See the snippet below for example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    jQuery("#date").datepicker('setDate', new Date('2017-08-18')); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://themetrace.com/demo/shamcey/css/style.default.css" >
<!--<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" >-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

Date Input: <input id="date" type="text" />
```